# How do I prevent multiple duplicate events from firing on a dynamic form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks, cocoon-gem

I have a dynamic form that allows you to add more child records as needed. I'm using the cocoon ruby gem. I got auto-save working on a form using the following code:

```
  <script>

  $(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {

    var $form = $('form.autosave');
    var saving = false;

    function autoSaveForm(actionPath) {
      var data = $form.serialize();
      console.log("POST: " + actionPath);
      var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      request.open('POST', actionPath, true);
      request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
      request.send(data);
      request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if(request.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && request.status === 200) {
          saving = false;
        }
      };
    }

    $form.on('blur', 'input', function() {
      if (saving) {
        return; // don't do the blur action
      }
      saving = true;
      var actionPath = $form.attr('action');
      autoSaveForm(actionPath);
    });

  });

  </script>
```

The "blur" event is being triggered two times. Here's my console output:

```
POST: /user/profile VM1717:9 
POST: /user/profile VM1717:9
```

**I've updated my code from @samanime's suggestion to add a boolean to prevent the event being triggered 4 times. Now it is only triggered twice. Progress!**

**It appears the issue is with turbolinks and how I setup my JS.**

Comment: I also found out that you shouldn't use inline JS with turbolinks. This doesn't solve the issue, but anyone else using this approach should known about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a boolean to track if you're currently saving, and then don't do it again if you are.

```
var saving = false;
$form.on('blur', function () {
    if (saving) {
        return; // don't do the blur action
    }

    saving = true;
    // do saving stuff
});
```

And then you'll need to watch when you're done saving, and then set `saving` back to false.

```
function autoSaveForm(actionPath) {
    // other stuff
    request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if(request.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && request.status === 200) {
            saving = false;
        }
    };
}
```

If you wanted to, you could also take that a step farther and have another boolean (like `needsToSave`) which would get marked true if you tried to save while saving, and then immediately start saving the latest stuff as soon as the first saving was done.

Comment: Thanks for this idea! I'm implementing it now, but I'm getting an error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: xhr is not defined". Where exactly do I initialize xhr?

Comment: I just realized xhr is request. You were just naming it differently.

Comment: Your soultion is partly working. Now I get two triggers:

Comment: `POST: /user/profile VM1717:9 
POST: /user/profile VM1717:9 `

Comment: @BagoCamembert Sorry about the `xhr` thing. I copied and pasted that line and forgot to change the variables. I've updated the code. Can you add to your question to show your current code?

Comment: @BagoCamembert From the code you've posted, I see no reason it would be triggering more than once now. What I suspect might be going on is you're doing something like accidentally adding that code/script in twice, each of which trigger simultaneously but independently.

Comment: I agree. I think it has to do with turbolinks, which is a separate issue. I'll accept your answer. THANK YOU!

Comment: I just noticed something else strange. When I tab away from the browser, and then tab back to it, it triggers another POST. XD

Comment: @BagoCamembert Yup, if you have anything in the form focused then tab away, that also triggers a blur.